# Getting "NoSuchKey" error when creating S3 signedUrl with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to access an S3 bucket with `nodejs` using `aws-sdk`.

When I call the `s3.getSignedUrl` method and use the url it provides, I get a "NoSuchKey" error in the url.

```
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>{MY_BUCKET_NAME}/{REQUESTED_FILENAME}</Key>
```

My theory is that the request path I'm passing is wrong. Comparing my request:

`{BUCKET_NAME}.s3.{BUCKET_REGION}.amazonaws.com/{BUCKET_NAME}/{KEY}`

With the url created from the AWS console:

`{BUCKET_NAME}.s3.{BUCKET_REGION}.amazonaws.com/{KEY}`

Why is `aws-sdk` adding the "{BUCKET_NAME}" at the end?

NodeJS code:

```js
// s3 instance setup
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  region: BUCKET_REGION,
  endpoint: BUCKET_ENDPOINT, // {MY_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.{REGION}.amazonaws.com
  s3ForcePathStyle: true,
  signatureVersion: "v4",
});

const getSignedUrlFromS3 = async (filename) => {
    const s3Params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: filename,
      Expires: 60,
    };

    const signedUrl = await s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", s3Params);

    return { name: filename, url: signedUrl };
  };
```

Comment: I have my endpoint as `{MY_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.{REGION}.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK adds the bucket name in the path because you specifically ask it to:

```js
s3ForcePathStyle: true,
```

However, according to your comment, you use the bucket name in the endpoint already ("I have my endpoint as `{MY_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.{REGION}.amazonaws.com`") so your endpoint *isn't* meant to use path style...

Path style means using `s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key` instead of `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/key`. Forcing path style with an endpoint that actually already contains the bucket name ends up with `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key` which is interpreted as key `bucket/key` instead of `key`.

The fix should be to disable `s3ForcePathStyle` and instead to set `s3BucketEndpoint: true` because you specified an endpoint for an individual bucket.

However, in my opinion it's unnecessary to specify an endpoint in the first place - just let the SDK handle these things for you! I'd remove both `s3ForcePathStyle` and `endpoint` (then `s3BucketEndpoint` isn't needed either).

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you :D I had to make 2 changes:
(1) Removed the `s3ForcePathStyle` flag (copied that from somewhere, learned to be very selective of what arguments I choose to paste now)
(2) Changed my `ENDPOINT` to just `s3.{REGION}.amazonaws.com (removed the leading {BUCKET_NAME})

Comment: If I didn't do #2 (with forcePathStyle disabled), it ended up requesting `{BUCKET_NAME}/{BUCKET_NAME}.s3.{REGION}.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean. I also could've done ENDPOINT = `s3.{REGION}.amazonaws.com` with forcePathStyle _enabled_. So i basicaly mixed those up, which ended up in an awkward url.

Comment: I amended my answer. It'll be best not to use any endpoint at all.